# EXTJS Gauge Chart Custom Label

Tags: extjs4.2, gauge

I am working on EXTJS Gauge chart.

In the gauge chart label I am trying to add % after the label value like 10%, 20% etc.

I am not able to get the value of the label.

Can any one help me to get the value of the label, so that I can draw label with returning value + '%' using drawLabel function.

Here is the image of my gauge.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from following link:
[Change field labels on an ExtJS chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098940/change-field-labels-on-an-extjs-chart)

Added following lines after the comment:

```
axes: [
    {
        type: 'gauge',
        position: 'gauge',
        minimum: 0,
        maximum: 100,
        steps: 10,
        margin: 10,
        /*These lines added*/
        label:
        {
            renderer: function(value)
            {
                return value + "%";
            }
        }
    }],
```

Now the label text is changed.

Thanks